# Why does conda look for a package in a channel not listed in the .condarc file?

Tags: python, conda

I am struggling to install packages on Win10 computer where I have no admin privileges and I have restricted access to the Internet throughout our corporate infrastructure. I have Python 3.6 with couple of other packages installed and I'd like clone the environment to do some experiments. As I must install packages only from the repository of the corporate, I have added the following line to the `condarc` file placed in my `%userprofile%` directory:

```
ssl_verify: false

channels:
  - https://uname:password@corporateURL/repository/type
```

Now if I try to clone the base environment with `conda create --clone base --name exp_env`, it gets all the packages except one, downloading and extracting packages shows 0% at that packege, and tells me that

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/pckname-version-pyversion.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

However, I am able to download that package with my browser from the Internet and from the repository fo the corporate too.

1. Why does conda look for that package outside the channel I gave to it in the `.condarc` file?
2. Why cannot conda download that package even I can download it with my browser?
3. How to solve the problem by

   1. telling conda to use the repository of the corporate
   2. Downloading the package manually and feed conda with that file?

### Additional info

I masked out some of the irrelevant info, but these are the things conda tells:

```
(base) %userprofile%>conda info

     active environment : base
    active env location : %ProgramFiles%\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : %userprofile%\.condarc
 populated config files : %userprofile%\.condarc
          conda version : X
    conda-build version : T
         python version : Z.final.0
       base environment : %ProgramFiles%\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://user:password@corporateURL/repository/type/win-64
                          https://user:password@corporateURL/repository/type/noarch
                          https://user:password@www.corporateURL/repository/type2/win-64
                          https://user:password@www.corporateURL/repository/type2/noarch
                          https://user:password@corporateURL/repository/type3/win-64
                          https://user:password@corporateURL/repository/type3/noarch
          package cache : %ProgramFiles%\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          %userprofile%\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : %userprofile%\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          %ProgramFiles%\Anaconda3\envs
                          %userprofile%\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/X requests/Y CPython/Z Windows/10 Windows/S
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```